# Android Getting started with Sugar ORM

Tags: android, sugarorm

i'm newbie in SugarORM and i want to use this library into my application. after set this library meta-tags i must be Extend SugarRecord for all the classes, for this action i'm create new class as Product as this sample

```
@Table
public class ProductTable {
    private String id;
    private String count;

    public ProductTable() {
    }

    public ProductTable(String id, String count) {
        this.id = id;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

and for Extend SugarRecord i'm want to have class as this sample:

```
public class ProductModel extends SugarRecord<ProductModel> {
    String title;
    String edition;

    public ProductModel(){
    }

    public ProductModel(String title, String edition){
        this.title = title;
        this.edition = edition;
    }
}
```

but i get this error:

```
Error:(9, 46) java: type com.orm.SugarRecord does not take parameters
```

for this line:

```
public class ProductModel extends SugarRecord<ProductModel> {
```

i'm using this [Document](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to extend `SugarRecord<ProductModel>` anymore, just `SugarRecord` will do it.

Comment: thanks sir, whats `ProductModel` between `<>` thats class structure?

Comment: That is a generic argument as ProductModel is what it is called a `Generic Class`. Take a look at the docs for better understanding 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html